# only load contents within body using ajax - jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to load only the contents of the **body** of a page(sample.html) and append it to body of another page(index.html) .. how can this be done..sorry i'm a noob

I used the below code .. but this doesn't seem to work properly

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/site/pages/sample.html",
    success: function(data){
        $('body').append(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try :

```
$('body').load('/site/pages/sample.html body');
```

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

See [Loading page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) in the `load()` docs

### Update:

As pointed out by @Windkiller in the comments - this will duplicate the `body` element on the document. A better solution would be to use get and replace the contents of `body` like this for example :

```
$.get("/site/pages/sample.html body", function(data) {
     $("body").replaceWith(data);
});
```

Comment: Your code will make 2 bodies in document. Becouse it does something like $('body').html(data) and data already contains body...

Comment: @Windkiller It will replace the `body` not duplicate it.

Comment: @ManseUK Do a simple test, run console and input: $("body").load("/ body");

Comment: @Windkiller added an alternative solution that prevents the duplication

Comment: This filters out the body and the head, but still includes children from the head.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: Your update doesn't seem to work with a google doc embed, such as "https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vR3oKZcz-osB2lVto8N8pbBjorb_tbLZ-i_VXRKlqcimthXrbjJ7sbdsnQ5WuQEOKg6U61xC8TloY5E/pub?embedded=true body"

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to let jQuery filter out the `<body>` element in the returned markup, then use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to obtain its children, including text nodes, and append them to the document body:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/site/pages/sample.html",
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).contents().appendTo("body");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks frederic .. but $(data).find("body").contents().appendTo("body"); doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Strange, that should work, assuming the markup you receive does contain a `<body>` element... Do you see a message in your browser's error console? If so, can you post it here?

Comment: I finally understood what's going on: jQuery already filters the `<body>` element from the markup by itself, so `find("body")` will not match anything. My updated answer should work as expected.

Comment: hi.. that worked but somehow the <title>my sample page</title> is also showing up in the body tag .. really wired

Comment: Yup, it appears the `<head>` element is filtered out, but not the `<title>` element. Does @ManseUK's answer give better results, since jQuery is supposed to match only the `<body>` element in that case?

Comment: thanks frederic!   .. manseuk's answer worked .. and it fetches only content in the body

Answer (score 1):

Either modify sample.html and strip down what you don't need from it (if you only access it through ajax) or: think of the data returned by the ajax function as a long string and copy from it only what you need.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/site/pages/sample.html",
    success: function(data){
        $('body').append(parseReturnData(data));
    }
});
```

where parseReturnData only returns what you need from the actual page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this
declare a div where you want to show the page

```
  <div id="managePage"> </div>
```

add this code in script code

```
 $('#managePage').load(pageName);
```

If want to add on click then use onclick or else you can use according to your requirement